# Pythonians: Is there a better way to code this in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, readability

I'm a senior PHP and Perl dude, but Python is new to me. I'm enjoying learning it! I wrote the below code, but I can't shake off the feeling that it could be better written by someone with "senior level" Python skills. Are you true Pythonians up to a fun challenge?

Please note: I want the code to readable. Python is suppose to be readable - we are not writing Perl here people! (example: I like that 'weekday' is a string instead of an integer, makes it VERY clear)

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
weekday = today.strftime("%a")
hourmin = int(today.strftime("%H%M"))
print "today here is: " + today.strftime("%c") # for debug
if weekday == "Sat" or \
   (weekday == "Sun" and hourmin < 2000) or \
   (weekday == "Fri" and hourmin > 1630) or \
   (hourmin >= 1630 and hourmin < 2000) :
    print "bad time"
else:
    print "good time"
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Lol since when are Sat and Sun weekdays?

Comment: I'd be really careful with converting the weekday to a string -- this wil make your code locale dependent.  It's much better to use `today.weekday()` (or `today.isoweekday()` if you prefer that numbering) and define constants for the weekdays.

Comment: FYI it's "pythonistas" not "pythonians" :)

Comment: The only real difference I'd make is I'd wrap the whole expression on the if inside parens and then get rid of the line continuations.

Comment: This is a bit of an abuse of `strftime`.  I'd rather use a `time` object representing the offsets, and extract the time from the object you have with `today.time()`.

Comment: @sven - true, but there is NO danger that this program will ever run outside the USA.

Comment: This needs to be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can map a day string to a lambda that takes hourmin and determines whether it is bad or not. For example:

```
# establish the "rules"    
bad_time = {
    'Sat': lambda h: True,    # always bad time!
    'Sun': lambda h: h < 2000,
    'Fri': lambda h: h > 1630,
}

# ... get your `weekday` and `hourmin` values

is_bad = bad_time.get(weekday, lambda h: (1630 <= h < 2000))(hourmin)
print 'bad time' if is_bad else 'good time'
```

*edit*: Follow kindall's advice.

Comment: Actually this is a lot more confusing than the original. In Perl this might be cute, but Python emphasizes readability over cleverness.

Comment: I'd like to here what you pythonistas think of this code. If I were writing this in Perl, I'd do it in a heartbeat!

Comment: Personally I'm not experienced with lambdas to write code like this confidently, but this is more readable to me. If someone didn't understand lambdas that would be a different story. Interestingly Guido hates lambdas, so my opinion is contrary to the creator's :)

Comment: It doesn't look like a place to use lambda rather a place to use xrange (or range in python3) and checking for membership.

Comment: @JBernardo: No, this seems like a classic case of good lambda use.

Comment: There are a couple of things I think hinder the readability of this code. First is the infrequently-used `get()` method of `dict`. Second is the use of `bad_weekday` which, used with `get()`, looks more like an error code than a function reference.  If you're going to use lambdas I'd just go whole hog and write `bad_weekday` as a lambda in the `get()` call.  And I'd use `is_bad` as a Boolean rather than a function, i.e., just call the function immediately after getting it since there's no reason to store it: `is_bad = bad_time.get(weekday, lambda h: 1630<= h < 2000)(hourmin)`

Comment: @kindall I wrote this quick-and-dirty. But I think I agree with your assessment.

Comment: Pretty sick, but I still don't understand it simply by looking. Perhaps one day I will be skilled enough with lambda functions to appreciate your skills at face value.

Answer (score 3):

In python you can continue on the next line if you have unmatched parens, no need for the backslash. You can also do two comparisons in one boolean expression.

```
if (weekday == "Sat" or
    (weekday == "Sun" and hourmin < 2000) or
    (weekday == "Fri" and hourmin > 1630) or
    1630 <= hourmin < 2000):
    print "bad time"
else:
    print "good time"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using a class that lets you easily determine whether a time is in a predefined range, then putting instances of this class in a dictionary to record the times each day is "bad." Perhaps use a couple of predefined ranges for convenience and ease of changing later.

```
class hmrange(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start, self.end = start, end
    def __contains__(self, hm):
        return self.start <= hm < self.end

alldayhours  = hmrange(0000, 2400)
weekdayhours = hmrange(1630, 2000)

badhours = {
    'Sun': hmrange(0000, 2000)
    'Mon': weekdayhours
    'Tue': weekdayhours
    'Wed': weekdayhours
    'Thu': weekdayhours
    'Fri': hmrange(1630, 2400)
    'Sat': alldayhours
}

badtime =  hourmin in badhours[weekday]
```

Comment: Or even better, have each of the values in the badtime dict be a time range, and check for `hourmin in badtime[currentday]`. :)

Comment: I like this. It looks readable and maintainable. How about adding a tuple unzipping line like: `startBadTime, endBadTime = badHours[weekday]`. Then you could tidy up that last line of code to look like this: `badtime = startBadTime <= hourmin < endBadTime`. Readability win!

Comment: `weekdayhours = xrange(1630, 2000+1)` then you check for membership. `badtime = now in badhour[today]`

Comment: I could use a `namdetuple` for that too, I guess.  :-)

Comment: Actually, I didn't realize `xrange` supported `in`. That's pretty sweet and simplifies this enormously. You really do learn something every day on SO...

Comment: On further thought, it looks as though `xrange` actually checks for `in` by iterating through the whole range, as it doesn't have a `__contains__` method. So maybe that's not the best way. I'll rewrite that to use a custom class. From [this page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips): "In Python versions before 2.2, xrange objects also supported optimizations such as fast membership testing (i in xrange(n)). These features were removed in 2.2 due to lack of use."

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
weekday = today.strftime("%a")
hourmin = int(today.strftime("%H%M"))
print "today here is: " + today.strftime("%c") # for debug
days = ["Sun", "Fri"]
times = [2000, 1630]
if weekday == "Sat" or \
    weekday in days and hourmin < times[days.index(weekday)] or \
    2000 > hourmin >= 1630:
    print "bad time"
else:
    print "good time"
```